# Controlling orientation of pie charts in R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am plotting a network of nodes in igraph where some of the nodes are pies while others are solids. When I specify a node with two parts, I always get a node vertically divided into two. Is there a way to control the orientation of this line of division? For example, in the example node shown below (cropped form my bigger plot), can I make the division line go east-west or northwest-southeast (ideally any degree of rotation) instead of north-south? There is a pie.angle variable in the API but it didn't help when I played around with it. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Update: I am specifically looking for a solution within igraph, i.e., how to change orientation of the dividing line when one of the nodes in my igraph plot is defined to be of type "pie".

[image: An example of the kind of nodes I am able to produce]

Answer (score 0):

use init.angle 0 for nothing and 90 for right angle shift  see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/pie.html

```
> data(mtcars)
> attach(mtcars)
> par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 > pie(table(cyl))
> pie(table(cyl),init.angle=45)
> pie(table(cyl),init.angle=60)
> pie(table(cyl),init.angle=90)
```

[image]

or you can also use plotly https://plot.ly/r/pie-charts/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doesn't seem to work from within igraph which is what I am looking for. I will edit the question to make it clearer. igraph doesn't recognize vertex.pie.init.angle. vertex.pie.angle which igraph does recognize doesn't seem to work as I had already mentioned.